# Firebase Database - Page counter requires 'write = true' in rules?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, counter, firebase-security

Essentially every time a person clicks on my website, it adds one to the counter on my real-time database. However, If I want to add that to my database, it's saying that write has to equal true. Similar applies to when retrieving data, it requires read to equal true.

Now if write was to equal to true, wouldn't anyone who enters the website be able to alter my private database? 
Furthermore, if read was to equal true, wouldn't anyone who enters the website be able to read my private database?

How would I be able to add the counter in my database privately without allowing others changing or viewing my database?

Answer (score 1):

What you're saying is true - if someone has write access to the child with the counter, they can mess with its value in a way that's inconsistent with the way you might expect.

If you need 100% protection from malicious clients, you will need to implement the write logic on a backend you control.  The backend can use the Firebase Admin SDK to modify the counter.  Since the SDK always bypasses security rules, the user can be denied write access from the client, while your backend operates as normal.  Your client will have to invoke the backend rather than write the database directly, and your backend can also check to see if the user ought to be able to increment the value.  That said, your API endpoint can still be abused by the end user, so you might need to write code to protect against that as well.

Comment: This is a little confusing. Could you link me to resources that may break this down a little simpler? Thanks, really appreciate this.

Comment: This is about as simple as it gets.  You're going to have to involve a backend in order to avoid writes directly from the client, and there's no way to simplify that whole process. Maybe look into Cloud Functions for an easy backend, but there's still going to be a lot to learn.

Comment: what if I were to do something like, /rules/counter { .read: false, write: true }. Would that allow me to change the counter variable but prevent the public from viewing the data? Or are they still able to write the database regardless if read is false?